# Apply multiple filters based on user input (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to ask the user:

1. Which field/column to apply filters to?
2. How many filters are to be applied?

I want to take those *n* filters as input and apply them to the field of that column.

Refer these images:
[Before applying filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ut9O.jpg),
[After applying filters to Column A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEL58.jpg)

Code:

```
Sub MultiFilter()
Dim colNumber As Integer, numberOfFilters As Integer
Dim filters(10) As String

'Column number to apply filters to
colNumber = InputBox("Enter column number to apply filter to (Column A = 1, B = 2, etc.)")

'Number of filters to apply
numberOfFilters = InputBox("Number of filters to apply to Column " & colNumber)

'Take multiple filters as input
For i = 0 To numberOfFilters - 1
    filters(i) = InputBox("Filter #" & i + 1)
Next i

'Apply multiple filters
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Activate
    .Range("A1").Select
    .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    For i = 0 To numberOfFilters - 1
        'ISSUE!
        Selection.AutoFilter field:=colNumber, Criteria1:=filters(i)
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Inputs: 1, 2, A, B

I realise that I'm selecting over `Criteria1` multiple times. I've come across the following code:

`Range("A1:D10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("A", "B"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`

The above code works perfectly, but I have to hard code the values "A" and "B". Is there a way to replace that with *n* user inputs?

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Going a step further, how do I take *number of columns* as a user input and apply multiple filters to multiple columns?

*Example:*
(Refer images)

Columns: 1, 2 ("Doc Type", "Year")
Filters: 2 in column 1 ("A", "C"), 2 in column 2 ("2016", "2017")

Comment: I don't see any `Redim` on `filters` before stuffing values into the array.

Comment: What about filtering multiple columns?

Comment: @Jeeped, thanks for the tip! Filtering multiple columns seems to be my next task. I'm looking for solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing all the `With` bloc by the simple:

```
  'Apply multiple filters
   Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.AutoFilter colNumber, Filters, xlFilterValues
```

Besides, as noted by @Jeeped you need to resize the `filters` array according to user input

```
Dim filters() As String ' <--- dont specify size here
....
'Number of filters to apply
numberOfFilters = InputBox("Number of filters to apply to Column " & colNumber)
Redim filters(0 to numberOfFilters - 1) As String  '<-- resize according to user input
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It worked.

I'm new to VBA. Thanks for the tip on resizing the array!

Comment: Good to be here! :)